# Kendo Ajax Delete in a grid

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Using Kendo Grid and MVC 4

In my controller when it errors out I send a error message:

```
    return this.Json(new DataSourceResult
        {
            Errors = "my custom error"
        });
```

The error is nicely displayed, however the item is visually removed from the grid, even though not from the data source. Refreshing the grid puts it back.

How do I have the grid not delete a record visually when it receives an error in the delete method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass error message from controller to view , you need to use ModelState, see below:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Delete", "my custom error");
return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
```

You also can use an empty string for the key:

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "my custom error");
return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
```

**Update**

Without your code, it's hard to imagine where the problem is exactly. You can try below code and see how it works for you . But maybe the problem comes from your Kendo grid code.

```
   var model = new YourBuildingModel();
   model = GetModelList();
   //
   ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "my custom error");
   var buildingData = (new List<YourBuildingModel> {model}).ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState);
   return Json(buildingData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Hi Lin, that does send an error message and I can get it via the Grid's error event, but the grid still visually makes the change to the grid. (adds or removes or edits the model) How do I prevent the edit that causes the error to display.

Comment: hi @BahaiResearch.com, I updated my answer. But if it still doesn't work, please provide more of your code.